# How to build a web page with flexible component?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, less, frontend

I have an idea of building web page (without backend, because sometimes I just need to build a static page) with flexible component. But I have met some problem.

I assumed the folder structure like this:

```
components
|__________header
           |______header.tpl(any js template is ok)
           |______header.less
           |______header.js
|__________footer
           |______footer.tpl
           |______footer.less
           |______footer.js
|__________news-list
           |______news-list.tpl
           |______news-list.less
           |______news-list.js
```

The very simple structure is as above. When I want to build a page.I could just import the the template to the index.html of the small static project.May somebody will use the `inline()`function to add a component in the index.html,just like `inline('components/header')`.
But I don't know how to realize it.I will use the grunt to complie the less and combine the output css,as well as the javascript would be processed in the same way. Idealy,the index.html can be compile(render) to static page with grunt.
Can anyone help me to achive my thought?Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try ejs: http://www.embeddedjs.com along with some associated grunt tools: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ejs-static

Comment: Thanks.But I found that the plugin just render the .ejs to a .html file,but in the .html file, the ejs symbols like `<%= name %>` still avaliable.If the .html file can store the final render results will be better.